# Cobertura maven plugin when to download

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

Can anyone tell me to locate and download the cobertura maven plugin?  I've looked on the web.  On the Corbertura homepage there is a URL http://maven-plugins.sourceforge.net/repository/maven-plugins/ to the download, but that page is dead.

Comment: Please ignore this last question I've found my problem.

Comment: You should edit the question or provide an answer yourself about what the problem was.  This will help people in the future that have similar problems.

Answer (score 4):

The Cobertura plugin for Maven can be downloaded from the [Maven central repository](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin/), however you shouldn't need to download the plugin directly, it is sufficient to declare the plugin in your POM, Maven will download it automatically from the central repository (assuming you have an internet connection).

The configuration would be something like this:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```